# NHibernate Save and Commit in one Transaction

Tags: c#, nhibernate, unit-of-work

I have the following code that creates a new bookmark and adds one or more tags to it. If a tag does not already exist it is created and added to the bookmark.

```
Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
bookmark.Title = request.Title;
bookmark.Link = request.Link;
bookmark.DateCreated = request.DateCreated;
bookmark.DateModified = request.DateCreated;
bookmark.User = _userRepository.GetUserByUsername(request.Username);

IList<Tag> myTags = _tagRepository.GetTags(request.Username);
IList<string> myTagsToString = myTags.Select(x => x.Title).ToList<string>();

foreach (var tag in request.Tags)
{
    if (myTagsToString.Contains(tag))
    {
        Tag oldTag = myTags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Title == tag);
        bookmark.Tags.Add(oldTag);
    }
    else
    {
        Tag newTag = new Tag();
        newTag.Title = tag;
        newTag.User = _userRepository.GetUserByUsername(request.Username);
        newTag.DateCreated = request.DateCreated;
        newTag.DateModified = request.DateCreated;
        bookmark.Tags.Add(newTag);
    }
}

_bookmarkRepository.Add(bookmark);
_uow.Commit();
```

I implemented unit of work but I am not sure if I did this correctly. I use the save method followed by a commit. The save method inserts the bookmark and tags to the database and the commit method does an insert to the junction table (bookmarks have many tags and tags have many bookmarks).

So everything is inserted correctly. But if I remove the commit method the bookmark and tags still get inserted. But their is no insert to the junction table. Does this mean these inserts are not in the same transaction since commit is not necessary to save the bookmark and tags to the database? The commit is only necessary to save the relationship between tags and bookmarks.

EDIT:

Repository

```
public abstract class Repository<T, TEntityKey> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
    private IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().SaveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Save(entity);
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Delete(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
    {
        ICriteria criteriaQuery = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().CreateCriteria(typeof(T));

        return (List<T>)criteriaQuery.List<T>();
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork

```
public class NHUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public void RegisterAmended(IAggregateRoot entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().SaveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    public void RegisterNew(IAggregateRoot entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Save(entity);
    }

    public void RegisterRemoved(IAggregateRoot entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Delete(entity);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BookmarkRepository

```
public class BookmarkRepository : Repository<Bookmark, int>, IBookmarkRepository
{
    public BookmarkRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:
I changed NHUnitOfWork to this:**

```
public class NHUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private ITransaction _transaction;

    public void RegisterAmended(IAggregateRoot entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().SaveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    public void RegisterNew(IAggregateRoot entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Save(entity);
    }

    public void RegisterRemoved(IAggregateRoot entity)
    {
        SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Delete(entity);
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        using (_transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                _transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**So I can use it like this:**

```
_uow.BeginTransaction();

Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
bookmark.Title = request.Title;
bookmark.Link = request.Link;
bookmark.DateCreated = request.DateCreated;
bookmark.DateModified = request.DateCreated;
bookmark.User = _userRepository.GetUserByUsername(request.Username);

IList<Tag> myTags = _tagRepository.GetTags(request.Username);
IList<string> myTagsToString = myTags.Select(x => x.Title).ToList<string>();

foreach (var tag in request.Tags)
{
    if (myTagsToString.Contains(tag))
    {
        Tag oldTag = myTags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Title == tag);
        bookmark.Tags.Add(oldTag);
    }
    else
    {
        Tag newTag = new Tag();
        newTag.Title = tag;
        newTag.User = _userRepository.GetUserByUsername(request.Username);
        newTag.DateCreated = request.DateCreated;
        newTag.DateModified = request.DateCreated;
        bookmark.Tags.Add(newTag);
    }
}

_bookmarkRepository.Add(bookmark);
_uow.Commit();
```

I added a begin transaction to the NHUnitOfWork implementation. This means I need to call _uow.BeginTransaction() before any select or insert and in the end call _uow.Commit(). This seems to work if I look at NHibernate Profiler. If this is wrong please tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Save` methods are not executed inside a transaction, because you close *and open* the transaction in the `Commit` method.

The correct implementation would be to start the transaction *before* calling `Save`.

Comment: To clarify, the correct implementation would be to begin the transaction BEFORE DOING ANY CHANGES AT ALL (this includes Save(), but also e.g. Get()+property modification, since NHibernate can (with default settings) decide to perform the database change at any time.

Comment: @Oskar: Do you have an example of this? I know of sequences in Oracle that are used for the ID that are accessed before the commit, but I am not aware of any other such case.

Comment: Actually, from NHibernate it's not really "at any time" - but from the point of view of a complex application, it can be very hard to control when exactly modifications are transmitted. The point is that Commit() is only one possible way to trigger Flush(). See the reference for when Flush() can occur automatically: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing

Comment: From that reference section, we also learn that Save() will only result in immediate INSERT if it's required to get the primary key.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope this is the right way to do it but it seems to work.

Comment: @Mr.nuub: Your transaction is not rolled back if there is an exception in the code between `BeginTransaction` and `Commit`. In fact, your UoW doesn't even provide the possibility to do so.

Comment: Should I add this within a try/catch and put a rollback in the unit of work? try { begin transaction and commit } catch { if exception rollback }

Comment: @Mr.nuub: Yes, that's what you need to do.